# how to populate a test function with given input-golang

Tags: go, testing, input

I have the following code

```
func TestBookingListing_provisionHistory(t *testing.T) {
    Setup(false)

    b := Booking{
        
        Status: StatusActive,
    
        ListingIDs: []int64{1, 2},
    }

    for _, l := range b.ListingIDs {

        bl := BookingListing{
            BookingID:   b.ID,
            ListingID:   l,
            Created:     b.Created,
            Status:      StatusPending,
            RequestedBy: "Jane",
            Type:        b.Type,
            Updated:     b.Created,
        }

        
        if Status(bl.RequestedBy) != StatusExpired {

            t.Error("expecting status of bookinglisting to be requested")

        }

    }
}
```

I need to display the name of Requestedby in when the status is not expired.
How can this be done
thanking in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you'd just have to do something this:

```golang
// other code here...

if Status(bl.RequestedBy) != StatusExpired {
    t.Error("expecting status of bookinglisting to be requested")
    return
}

fmt.Printf("requested by: %s\n", bl.RequestedBy)

// ...
```

or if the test shouldn't return if the status is expired:

```golang
// other code here...

if Status(bl.RequestedBy) != StatusExpired {
    t.Error("expecting status of bookinglisting to be requested")
} else {
    fmt.Printf("requested by: %s\n", bl.RequestedBy)
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thank you,but i am only able to see the output in the debug console not terminal and the output is coming twice in the debug console requested by: Jane
requested by: Jane
PASS

Comment: What debug console are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You want t.Errorf not t.Error, then you can insert the value:

```
if Status(bl.RequestedBy) != StatusExpired {
   t.Errorf("incorrect bookinglisting status got:%d want:%d",bl.RequestedBy, StatusExpired)
}
```